can we optimize this elastic query for the better performance
elastic query:
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "((txtdisplayname:leave) OR (txtsearchkeyword:leave) OR (txtdisplayname:leave*) OR (txtsearchkeyword:leave*)) AND (txtbenefitid:* OR txtbenefitid:NULL)"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "source": "def order = ['Manage Leave','Holiday Calendar','Onsite Leave']; int index = order.indexOf(doc['txtdisplayname.keyword'].value); return index == -1 ? _score :_score *( 1.0 / (index + 1)) * 50;"
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

for the query leave i will be getting some few results in that if the manage leave, holiday calendar and Onsite Leave is present that i need to prioritize these results to the first and other results should follow them the above query is helping for the same, but was there any possibility to optimize the query is the doubt for the better performance.

You don't need to resort to scripted scoring. You can simply make your query string query in bool/must and then boost some results using bool/should with different boosting parameters for each of the values you want.
The boost values are easy to pick according to your script:

Manage Leave has index 0, so 1 / 1 * 50 = 50
Holiday Calendar has index 1, so 1 / 2 * 50 = 25.
Onsite Leave has index 2, so 1 / 3 * 50 = 17.

The following query should already be much more efficient:
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "((txtdisplayname:leave) OR (txtsearchkeyword:leave) OR (txtdisplayname:leave*) OR (txtsearchkeyword:leave*)) AND (txtbenefitid:* OR txtbenefitid:NULL)"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "txtdisplayname.keyword": {
              "query": "Manage Leave",
              "boost": 50
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "txtdisplayname.keyword": {
              "query": "Holiday Calendar",
              "boost": 25
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "txtdisplayname.keyword": {
              "query": "Onsite Leave",
              "boost": 17
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

The next performance hogger would be this wildcard search on a text field txtdisplayname:leave*, but I'll leave that for homework :-)
